# The recursive reflection of this rebus may be too revealing

Tags: rebus

Is the following rebus too self-evident?

> `iiib4`

Hint:

> It's in the title.

Comment: Three eyes before ?

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps *recursive reflection* refers to

> [code that examines itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful),

in which case `iiib4` refers to

> 3 before, i.e. three words before the code, which is
>  **REBUS**.

It would also explain the reference to the term *self-evident* as well as the now-deleted note to look at the `rebus` tag.

Answer (score 6):

The answer might be

> rebus

Argument:

> **iiib4** = three i's before
>  reflection of **iiib4** = after three i's
>  The first word after three **i**'s in the title "The recurs**i**ve reflect**i**on of th**i**s" is the word **rebus**

Comment: Can't really find if it's an English rule or not, but shouldn't the plural of letters use `'s` (apostrophe s) instead of an attached `s` (i.e. `I's` instead of `Is`). At first I kept reading the word `is` instead of multiple times the letter `i`..

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen: you may simply edit posts on this site yourself, to improve/correct the spelling.

Comment: I know, but since English is not my native language I wasn't 100% sure if it's an actual rule. Perhaps both `I's` and `Is` is grammatically correct, even though I personally prefer `I's` for better readability.

Answer (score 4):

Is it,

> Rebus

because

> iiib4 refers to three before the end in the title, and the recursion is that the answer to this rebus is rebus?

Comment: If you go with "title" instead of my version, you get "BE", or perhaps "MAY".

Answer (score 1):

how about

> it's right before my eyes

OR

> it's right before the eyes

rationale:

> { (iii) is "eyes" ["right before" (b4) (which must be, recursing reflexively,  put b4 the eyes)] (whose eyes? reflect on self) "my" } and finally "it's" is self referential to the very puzzle itself

OR

> "iiib4" referring to itself is "it's" and the (right "b4") must be put b4 (reflexive recursion) the "iii"'s or "eyes" and thus the rebus becomes self-evident